# I'm having trouble trying to show custom Text in Flutter when no data is coming from Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to develop a mobile application with Flutter. My goal is to show data from Firestore with `ListView.builder`. First of all, my codes are as follows:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:treedisaster/functions/constants.dart';
import 'package:treedisaster/model/Person.dart';
import 'package:treedisaster/model/User.dart' as myUser;

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
FirebaseAuth userDB = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class PersonsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<PersonsPage> createState() => _PersonsPageState();
}

List<Person> allPersons = [];

class _PersonsPageState extends State<PersonsPage> {
  isLogin() {
    if (userDB.currentUser != null) {
      return true;
    } else if (userDB.currentUser == null) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPersons();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Kişilerim",
          style: TextStyle(color: textColorBlack),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
        child: isLogin() == true
            ? StreamBuilder(
                stream: db
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(userDB.currentUser!.uid)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  }

                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Text('Not found data'); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                  }
                  else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final List<dynamic> personsList =
                        snapshot.data!.get('Persons');
                    final List<DocumentReference> personRefs = personsList
                        .map((person) => db.collection("users").doc(person))
                        .cast<DocumentReference>()
                        .toList();

                    return ListView.builder(
                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: personRefs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final Person person =
                            Person.fromDocument(snapshot.data!);
                        return Card(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: const [
                                Icon(Icons.person),
                              ],
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              "${person.Name} ${person.Surname}",
                            ),
                            trailing: InkWell(
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                  color: lightRed,
                                ),
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                    size: 25,
                                    color: textColorWhite,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return SizedBox();
                },
              )
            : Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  // ....
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getPersons() async {
    final DocumentSnapshot currentUserDoc =
        await db.collection("users").doc(userDB.currentUser!.uid).get();
    final Person person = Person.fromDocument(currentUserDoc);
    final List<Person> persons = [person];

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        allPersons = persons;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to show a custom Text if no data is coming from Firestore. But the code I wrote is not working. Why could it be? A blank page appears. It is still doing data checking. It is constantly renewed.

Thanks for help